# Java applet/dialog strange behavior

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, jdialog

I have a non-trivial Java applet. It has a menu, and via that menu applet shows a dialog that extends `JDialog`. Dialog is shown using `setVisible(true)`. When user finishes working with that dialog, dialog is closed (after pressing "done" button) using `this.dispose()`.

Now, there's a strange problem - applet works fine in Firefox, even in IE but in Chrome, when applet shows some other (dialog) window, that window is shown **behind** the applet. I have to click on the place where dialog should be in order to show it (bring it to front). If I click it again (while it's shown) it will disappear (go to background) again. Button clicks are working as usual, but whenever I click at popup window itself (even it's title-bar) it changes it's "visible" state.

Please, any idea what's wrong? How to resolve that bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// the applet will typically appear inside a Window, get a reference to it using:
Window parent = Window.getWindows()[0];
// use the window as the parent of a modal dialog.
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent);
dialog.setModal(true);
// ...
dialog.setVisible(true);
// won't be called until the applet is dismissed 
someJComponent.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Applets embedded in web pages will always be subject to modality and focus problems.  For a better user experience, launch the applet free-floating using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), or even better still, launch a frame using JWS.

Comment: Thank you, but problem persists... After closing any applet-made JDialog using "X" next time i open any window it's messed with focus. Any solution except switching from applets to smthg else?

Comment: See the last code lines I added in an edit.  Why so keen on an embedded applet?

Comment: No, added code won't do :\ I need to use applets cause i'm maintaining some old and very complicated code. Switching from applets would require rewrite of large part of the code.

Comment: *"No, added code won't do :\"* Flush the class cache before testing.  Insert debug statements to check you are getting the latest version of the code. *"I need to use applets.."*  I asked why an **embedded** applet?  If you don't know the meaning of the word, look it up or ask.

Comment: Yes, tested code but changed a bit interface to make sure it's not some cached copy (btw, applet is embedded using "param name="cache_option" value="no">" option). I never worked with applet, but my boss found a bug in code somebody else, some long time ago wrote and he asked me to resolve it but after hours of trying i simply couldn't find any explanation except that it's some sort of Chrome's bug while responding to "JDialog -> CloseBtnClicked" event...If it's just up to me, i wouldn't use applets at all :)

Comment: I will accept your answer cause you put an effort to help, but i'm sure it's some chrome bug...

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm guessing that `window` was supposed to be `parent` in that example?  (I would edit the code but don't have the SO rep yet.)

Comment: @TiStrga  You guessed right!  Hopefully you will gain the rep. to edit soon.  In the mean-time, I made the edit.